# Code for adding iptables rules using IPTC library in linux is not linking

Tags: c, linux, linker, iptables, iptc

I am trying to compile the example C code provided here http://www.bani.com.br/lang/en/2012/05/programmatically-managing-iptables-rules-in-c-iptc/

using (as described in the post):

```
cc `pkg-config –cflags –libs libiptc` iptablesExample_2.c -o iptablesExample_2
```

I have also tried compiling it using:

```
sudo gcc -g -o iptablesExample_2 iptablesExample_2.c -liptc -liptables -ldl
```

it did not work also and the error this time was:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liptables   
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried the example provided at the end of this 
http://wiki.tldp.org/iptc%20library%20HOWTO
And I had the same issues

> Linux kernel: 3.8.2    iptables version: v1.4.12

Comment: What is the output of running `pkg-config –cflags –libs libiptc` at the command line?

Comment: Where does `libiptables` come from? Does it compile without the linker option `-liptables`?

Comment: Thanks, it has been solved. I compiled it using   sudo gcc -g -o iptablesExample iptablesExample.c -liptc -lip4tc -lip6tc -ldl

Comment: You might like to add an answer to your own question and also accept is answer. This way SO detects you question as answered.